# Given an CFG determine if $\varepsilon \in L(G)$

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-free, formal-grammars

Given a context free grammar how am I able to determine if $\varepsilon \in L(G)$ ?

The only way I thought of is to systematically check if I can derive the empty word from the given grammar. (Assuming it's not in CNF)

Is my intuition right though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is not fully right. Consider the membership problem which is defined by $$L = \{ \langle G, w\rangle: G \ is \ a\ CFG \ that\ generates \ the\ finite \ word \ w\}$$ It is know that $L$ is decidable and the right way to prove this is by using CNF for CFGs. The problem with what you mentioned is the following. Let $G$ be a CFG and let $w\in \Sigma^*$ be a finite word. If $G$ is not in CNF form, then you propose the following: "systematically check" if there is a derivation for $w$ in $G$. Well, this is not a good idea. Assume that you go over all derivations in some lexical ordering and once you find a derivation for $w$, we stop. The problem with this approach is that we may not halt. As a specific example, consider the following CFG: the rules are $S\to A$, $A\to A|a$ , where:

- S is the strat variable.
- A is a variable.
- a is a letter (or terminal).

Clearly, $L(G) = \{ a\}$. But the algorithm suggested does not halt as you need to try an infinite number of derivations and check whether $\epsilon$ is derived by one of them. Indeed, you can apply the rule $A\to A$ as much as you like.

The nice thing about CNF form is that if a word $w$ is in $L(G)$, then it requires exactly $2|w| - 1$ derivation rules to derive $w$. Hence, in order to check whether $w$ is in $L(G)$, you only need to consider all derivations of length $2|w| -1$. In particular, the algorithm halts.

Comment: I see Your point. However how do I determine if $\varepsilon$ belongs to the given grammar in CNF, which by definition does not contain any $\varepsilon$ transformations? 

Does it mean, that after I'm done with the iteration and did not found the word I was looking for then $\varepsilon$ belongs to $L(G)$? 

Or does the iteration stops and accepts immediately on input $\varepsilon$?

Comment: This is not correct, the CNF form can contain the following rule: $S\to \epsilon$ where $S$ is the start variable. However, a variable that is not the start variable cannot derive $\epsilon$. Given this, you simply check whether $S\to \epsilon$ is in your CNF grammar.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the CFG to [Greibach normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form), and then simply check whether the rule $S\rightarrow \varepsilon$ exists.

In fact, you are asking whether there is a [parsing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Parsing) for CFG.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, yes. But is is not straightforward what means "systematically check".

Probably the best way is to determine all the *nullable* symbols of the grammar. Here a symbol $X$ is nullable if there exists a derivation $X\Rightarrow^* \varepsilon$. Then check whether axiom $S$ itself is nullable.

Now $X$ is nullable if there exists a production $X\to \varepsilon$ or (recursion) if there exists a production $X\to\alpha$ such that all symbols in $\alpha$ are nullable.
I think an algorithm for this repeatedly looks for productions of the type $X\to\alpha$ with $\alpha$ nullable, and marking the found $X$ as nullable.
The algorithm stops when after a cycle over all productions no new nullable symbols are found.

If your grammar is in Chomsky or Greibach normal form, then either generating $\varepsilon$ is ignored, or it can only occur at the first step with a special $S\to\varepsilon$ production. First transforming into Chomsky or Greibach normal form does not particularly help, as those transformations include determining the nullable symbols.